# Proxmox system rebooting without any reason? ^@ logged to syslog

Tags: proxmox, server-crashes, crashlytics

yesterday my proxmox-server rebooted hard without any reason that I could see.

The logs are showing

```
Sep  1 15:13:47 example kernel: [4514929.741761] Firewall: *UDP_IN Blocked* IN=vmbr0 OUT= MAC=ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:0c:c4:7a:77:38:28:08:00 SRC=123.123.123.123 DST=255.255.255.255 LEN=173 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=47121 DF PROTO=UDP SPT=17500 DPT=17500 LEN=153
^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^$
Sep  1 15:17:50 example systemd-modules-load[817]: Module 'fuse' is builtin
Sep  1 15:17:50 example systemd-modules-load[817]: Inserted module 'vhost_net'
Sep  1 15:17:50 example hdparm[856]: Setting parameters of disc: (none).
Sep  1 15:17:50 example systemd-fsck[1015]: /dev/sda3: Journal wird wiederhergestellt
Sep  1 15:17:50 example systemd-fsck[1015]: /dev/sda3: sauber, 314/62592 Dateien, 40617/250112 Blöcke
```

As I learned yesterday, the `^@` stands for a NULL byte. But why is it logged? Any explanations for that?